# How to apply solid Principles and clean code in react in a component with too much logic

Tags: javascript, reactjs, design-patterns, coding-style, solid-principles

I'm trying to apply solid Principles in react to have a clean code but it's so confusing.
Let me please explain the problem. I have a component which is asking the user to enter his Card, After that I have to verify if the card is valid, if no i should show an error to the user if so, i have to fetch data of the card , data are in XML so i have to do some parsing to get data.
I have also other components
But let me talk about this component when user enters Card
I made a component for that CardInput for the UI and useCard for fetching data, verifying and more
M'y question is that when i'm looking to the useCard component there are two Big functions one for fetching and the other for extracting data from XML , i have also one function to get the Price , so fetching the Price and extracting the XML. I'm having many props coming from the parent ,because i defined all states in parent , like CardNumber which enters the user , CardInfo which is the result of the fetch and the Price , the error and the loading also , and m'y component ended by many props of state and setState
I'm also wondering Can i create components which extract data from XML receiving the XMLResponse ? And how should i.name them ? Are they helper functions ? How Can i separate code when i have too much Logic which is all related , the component is doing one thing getting the card info , so he has to verify the card first , get data , and extract XML ? How Can i deal with that ?

Comment: Split into multiple components with parameter passing. Plus a clear separation of functions in each component and commenting for easy reading.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: This is what i'm already doing , have You read m'y question ?

Answer (score 1):

You have too many questions here, but the basic answer is that you have write things that aren't React components.

You should have a class that captures the state and implements business rules of the payment flow.  `PaymentFlow`, for example, might be a good name for it.  Your react components would interact with an instance of this class to figure out what state to display, and you can pass it down as a single prop where necessary.

Following SOLID principles, along with the `PaymentFlow` class, you would have interfaces the define what it's dependencies -- data fetchers and submitters -- have to do, and then inject these dependencies by passing instances of them to the `PaymentFlow` constructor.

Then you can write unit tests for the whole payment process that pass dummy implementations of the dependencies to the `PaymentFlow` constructor and put it through its paces, ensuring that it operates and response correctly in all cases.

It is important to move as much logic as possible out of React components and into classes that are independent from infrastructure like this, so you can test it in isolation and gain confidence that it is actually correct.

Comment: I'm using functional components , this is why is confusing, i'm not using classes, it's actually one question, i think to do it there is more than one step, this why it seems like more than one question, and sorry i didn't understand anything you said